# Value error with tf.scatter_nd_update in graph neural network model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, valueerror, encoder-decoder

I have a custom class I am working with in my encoder-decoder model, however I keep running across a ValueError in this line mask = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(mask , t1 , s1).

```
class GraphConstructor(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, nnodes, k, dim, layer_num, alpha=3):
        super(GraphConstructor, self).__init__()
        self.nnodes = nnodes
        self.layers_num = layer_num
        
        self.emb1 = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(nnodes, dim)
        self.emb2 = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(nnodes, dim)

        self.lin1 = []
        self.lin2 = []
        for _ in range(layer_num):
            self.lin1.append(tf.keras.layers.Dense(dim))
            self.lin2.append(tf.keras.layers.Dense(dim))

        self.k = k
        self.dim = dim
        self.alpha = alpha
        

    def call(self, idx, scale_idx, scale_set):
        nodevec1 = self.emb1(idx)
        nodevec2 = self.emb2(idx)

        adj_set = []

        for i in range(self.layers_num):
            nodevec1 = tf.nn.tanh(self.alpha * self.lin1[i](nodevec1 * scale_set[i]))
            nodevec2 = tf.nn.tanh(self.alpha * self.lin2[i](nodevec2 * scale_set[i]))
            a = tf.matmul(nodevec1, tf.transpose(nodevec2, perm=[1, 0])) - tf.matmul(nodevec2, tf.transpose(nodevec1, perm=[1, 0]))
            adj0 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.tanh(self.alpha * a))
            
            
            mask = tf.zeros([idx.get_shape()[0], idx.get_shape()[0]], dtype=tf.float32)
            mask = tf.fill(tf.shape(mask), 0.0)
            s1, t1 = tf.nn.top_k(adj0, k=self.k, sorted=True)
            
            mask = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(mask , t1 , s1)
            
            adj = adj0 * mask
            adj_set.append(adj)
```

The line referencing GraphConstructor is

```
self.gc = GraphConstructor(num_nodes, subgraph_size, node_dim, self.layer_num)
```

with num_nodes=774, subgraph_size=20, node_dim=40, self.layer_num=3.

I adapted this code for a PyTorch code base, so I'm not sure if that could be an issue.

The error I get is this:

ValueError: The inner -18 dimensions of output.shape=[774,774] must match the inner 1 dimensions of updates.shape=[774,20]: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 1 for 'magnn/graph_constructor/TensorScatterUpdate' (op: 'TensorScatterUpdate') with input shapes: [774,774], [774,20], [774,20].

I am using this in an encoder-decoder RNN model with a variable batch_size (?/None). Any help, guidance, or clarification would be incredibly helpful.